# How to manage backend of business finance manager

Tags: java, database, javafx, javafx-2

I am making a finance manager application (intended for Independent Pharmacy businesses) using JavaFX. I am finishing up the front end design of this application, but I am not sure how to tackle the storing of all the data that the users will be entering. I want to use all that data for various reports and graphs that the user can generate.

Do I need a backend database? What is the simplest solution? As a future feature, I would like to add the functionality of users being able to log into their account from home as well.

Comment: The application is not storing any medical related data. My parents are the pharmacy owners and we are honestly fed up with keeping track of all our incoming and outgoing money. We are simply storing the following info: Daily Profits from the Cash Register (Cash, Debit and Credit), Insurance Claims per day (and when we will receive the funds), Monthly Expenses (Rent, utilities, etc.), Inventory orders (when and how much more inventory are we ordering).

Answer (score 0):

database as backend is always good option. there are so many open source embedded rdbms like [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/). Otherwise you can use regular database like MySQL or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) . Final decision is upto you, do your own research and whichever you feel easy to use.

Comment: Hi JAVAC, thanks for your input. I just have a few more questions. Which option would you say is the most beginner friendly or has the best documentation and online resources. Also, would these solutions be able to be implemented online (would the user be able to access the application from home and from their business place?)?

Comment: MySQL or postgreSQL would have good documentation and learning resources  available.. what do you mean by implemented online to use in web application ? then yes you can use them